# Failed to Write File to Disk on large images

Tags: wordpress, upload

I'm getting the following error while trying to upload large files.

Failed to write file to disk.

I've changed the permissions on the wp-content folder to 755 and then 777 but still no luck. I've also added the following to the php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 720M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 180
```

After all this, I'm still unable to upload larger files say 5mb but i can upload smaller files.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello. There are many possible reasons for your error. Please review your server logs and post relevant messages and related lines of code.Add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to wp-config.php to see errors, if you do not have access to server logs. Then someone can answer your question, or you may solve problem yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

several ways I have tried before in commandline panel(the first 1 should always work fine):

1  give right permission to the right file folder:

```
sophie@ubuntu:~$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

2 Have you tried restarting the apache?

```
sophie@ubuntu:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

3 press **Ctrl and F5** to refresh the connection between computer and server